# Usuário com medalha de Crítico mas sem privilégio de votar contra

Tags: suporte, status-nãorepro, medalhas

Hoje fuçando no perfil dos outros vi um caso de um usuário que possui a medalha de crítico mas ele nunca deu um voto contra. Na verdade, ele sequer tem reputação para isso.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/7/critic?userid=1017

Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender como isso é possível?

Comment: Caraca, eu entrei no link pensando "Quem será esse indivíduo?" e é eu! Haha! Mas enfim @bigown eu dei um downvote na época que estávamos em closed beta, após a edição da pergunta por parte do usuário eu removi meu downvote. \o

Comment: agora temos certeza do que aconteceu exatamente, rs.. valeu!

Comment: Desculpe, vi rápido e pensei que o bigown que havia feito a pergunta...

Comment: Havia também a possibilidade de ter feito o downvote quando tinha privilégio, mas depois ofereceu pontos de reputação por alguma pergunta. Há essa possibilidade também (não é o caso, só estou dizendo que não é de se assustar tanto). :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aparentemente esse usuário criou sua conta ainda durante o beta privado, quando não havia restrição de reputação para votar contra (i.e. todos podiam votar contra). Se ele votou contra, se arrependeu, e retirou o voto, ele vai continuar com 0 votos contra - mas a medalha ele já vai ter ganhado, ela não é retirada junto com o voto... Creio que foi isso que aconteceu, não me parece se tratar de um bug.

(outra alternativa seria se o post no qual ele votou contra foi removido)

Comment: Hum, quanto a retirar o voto não sair a medalha eu entendo, o que eu não sabia era que não havia restrição no beta privado. Provavelmente é isso mesmo.